# using ngClass directive is throwing exception?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am having a small code snippet in my angular component HTML file. it uses ngClass directive. Unfortunately it's not working.  I am using angular 5 in my project.

in my component stylesheet (progress-panel.component.scss)

```
chart-title,
.chart-title-value {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

in the HTML file, (progress-panel.component.html) I am using the ngClass directive.

```
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'currency'" [ngClass]="{'chart-title-value' , 'text-right'}">
       {{ campaign.breakdown.total | pcCurrency }}
     <span class="text-muted">/ {{ campaign.budget | pcCurrency }}</span>
  </div>
```

however it is throwing some errors that i can see

```
compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
```

appreciate it if you can help
thank you

Comment: not sure what are you trying to do here.. i suppose, you want to apply certain class dynamically, on certain condition met

Comment: Starkbucks, you has an error in the sintax of [ngClass], see the docs:https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass. If you want a class depending conditions you can use `{'chart-title-value':(condition1),'text-right':(condition2)}` if the class are fixed you can use simple `class="chart-title-value text-right"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'currency'" [ngClass]="'chart-title-value text-right'">
     {{ campaign.breakdown.total | pcCurrency }}
     <span class="text-muted">/ {{ campaign.budget | pcCurrency }}</span>
</div>
```

will work.

But it is very odd you are not just using the css `class` html sector instead aka

```
<div class="chart-title-value text-right" *ngSwitchCase="'currency'">
     {{ campaign.breakdown.total | pcCurrency }}
     <span class="text-muted">/ {{ campaign.budget | pcCurrency }}</span>
</div>
```

I tend to only use the `ngClass` when i want to set stuff depending on component values aka

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': componentVariableBoolean, 'second': componentVariableBoolean}">...</some-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ngClass]="chart-title-value text-right"` instead of  `[ngClass]="{'chart-title-value' , 'text-right'}"`